# Descriptor for lazy loading

Tags: python, lazy-loading, descriptor

I wanted to implement lazy loading of variables, but I seem to misunderstand descriptors a bit. I'd like to have object variables, which on first access will call the obj.load() function which will initialize the variables with their real value. I wrote

```
class ToLoad(object):
    def __init__(self, loader_name="load")
        self.loader_name=loader_name

    def __get__(self, obj, type):
        if not (hasattr(obj, "_loaded") and obj._loaded):
            obj._loaded=True
            getattr(obj, self.loader_name)()
        return None

class Test(object):
    x=ToLoad()
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y=y

    def load(self):
        print("Loading {}".format(self.y))
        self.x=self.y

t1=Test(1)
t2=Test(2)
print("A", t1.x)
print("B", t2.x)
print("C", t1.x)
```

which fails to return the actual value on loading at least the first time. Could someone suggest another way to solve that problem? I'm not sure how to return the correct value in **get** since at that point I do not know that the attribute is called "x"? Any other way?

DAMN, can't answer my own question... So here is the
EDIT:
Thanks for the input! However, my load() function does not return the variable itself, since it loads many different variables. And I want to minimize the notation for using lazy loading. So I came up with a decorator

```
class to_load:
    def __init__(self, *vars, loader="load"):
        self.vars=vars
        self.loader=loader

    def __call__(self, cls):

        def _getattr(obj, attr):
            if attr in self.vars:
                getattr(obj, self.loader)()
                return getattr(obj, attr)
            else:
                raise AttributeError

        cls.__getattr__=_getattr
        return cls

@to_load("a", "b")
class Test:
    def load(self):
        print("Loading")
        self.a=1
        self.b=2

t=Test()
print("Starting")
print(t.a)
print(t.b)
#print(t.c)
```

Is that OK? I'm not sure if I'm breaking things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two problems here:

1. You return `None` from `__get__`, whereas it should be the value you want `x` to represent.
2. You do `x = y`, but your descriptor doesn't implement `__set__`.

So, instead of setting a "is loaded" flag, you should rather create an attribute with the actual value, and check for that. If you don't want it to be read-only, you should implement `__set__`. Otherwise, instead of `self.x = self.y` in `load`, return the value and let `__get__` to take care of the assignment.

```
class ToLoad(object):
    def __init__(self, var, func):
        self.var  = var
        self.func = func

    # style note: try to avoid overshadowing built-ins (e.g. type)
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        try:
            return getattr(obj, self.var)
        except AttributeError:
            value = getattr(obj, self.func)()
            setattr(obj, self.var, value)
            return value

class Foo(object):
    x = ToLoad('x', '_load_x')

    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y

    def _load_x(self):
        print('Loading {0} into x'.format(self.y))
        return self.y

a = Foo(1)
b = Foo(2)
print(a.x)
print(b.x)
print(a.x)
```

Comment: that gave me the idea for the decorator I mention in the EDIT. I wanted to avoid mentioning the variable names twice and moreover there is only one loading function (usually getting stuff from SQL and other sources which I merely don't want to connect to early or unneccessarily)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably more like this:

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y=y

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.load(attr)

    def load(self, attr):
        print("Loading `{}`".format(attr)) # ie "Loading `x`"
        # get the value for `attr` somewhere, here always self.y 
        val = self.y
        # store it on this object to avoid reloading it
        setattr(self, attr, val) 
        return val

t1=Test(1)
t2=Test(2)
print("A", t1.x)
print("B", t2.x)
print("C", t1.x)
```

To make your code work you need a few `return`s:

```
class ToLoad(object):
    def __init__(self, loader_name="load"):
        self.loader_name=loader_name

    def __get__(self, obj, type):
        if not (hasattr(obj, "_loaded") and obj._loaded):
            obj._loaded=True
            return getattr(obj, self.loader_name)()
        return None

class Test(object):
    x=ToLoad()
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y=y

    def load(self):
        print("Loading {}".format(self.y))
        self.x=self.y
        return self.x

t1=Test(1)
t2=Test(2)
print("A", t1.x)
print("B", t2.x)
print("C", t1.x)
```

Descriptors know on which object they are stored, but they don't know on which attribute. You want to intercept the access of a attribute, not change the returned value, so you want `__getattr__` instead of descriptors.

Comment: actually I don't want the returns since my load() function does not return the value (see EDIT)